# Delete Datagridview Cell(s) Selection

Tags: vb.net, datagridview

What I want to do is select rows(0).cells(0) to rows(1).cells(6) in a datagridview (just an example, selection will change), press a button and then all cells in the selected range delete or equal "".

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Have you attempted a solution? If yes, please show us how and describe what went wrong. This is a question and answer site, not a code writing or mentorship service.

Comment: Sorry, I'm new to this site. I have searched the web, but my search results just bring up deleting rows and not selection.

Comment: I've tried playing around with the code to see if something works, but have had no luck. The best I've come up with is me.datagridview1.selectedcells. . . but can't figure out how to delete from there, or maybe I'm on the completely wrong track.

Comment: No need to apologize for being new. You might find http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask useful as you learn the ropes.

Comment: I've figured it out. I would share the code, but it saying I'm entering too many characters. Basically I just got the code to search every cell in the datagrid and see if the cell was selected and if true then that cell = "". There is probably an easier method, but I can't figure it out.

Comment: Feel free to share your solution as an answer to your own question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the code:

```
    Private Sub clearpb_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clearpb.Click

    Dim myrowcount As Integer = Me.datagridviewentry.Rows.Count
    Dim mycolcount As Integer = Me.datagridviewentry.Columns.Count

    a = 0
    Do While a < myrowcount
        b = 0
        Do While b < mycolcount
            If Me.datagridviewentry.Rows(a).Cells(b).Selected = True Then
                Me.datagridviewentry.Rows(a).Cells(b).Value = ""
            End If
            b += 1
        Loop
        a += 1
    Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: Better answer:         For Each DataGridViewCell In Me.datagridviewentry.SelectedCells

            DataGridViewCell.value = ""

        Next